# Match to re-code letters and numbers in python (pandas)

Tags: python, r, pandas, match

I have a variable that is mixed with letters and numbers. The letters range from A:Z and the numbers range from 2:8. I want to re-code this variable so that it is all numeric with the letters A:Z now becoming numbers 1:26 and the numbers 2:8 becoming numbers 27:33.

For example, I would like this variable:

```
Var1 = c('A',2,3,8,'C','W',6,'T')
```

To become this:

```
Var1 = c(1,27,28,33,3,23,31,20)
```

In R I can do this using 'match' like this:

```
Var1 = as.numeric(match(Var1, c(LETTERS, 2:8)))
```

How can I do this using python? Pandas?

Thank you

Comment: can you please share with us your input data?

Comment: @nimrodz I made some edits to my question and provided an example

Comment: updated my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a dictionary and map the values:

```
import string
import numpy as np

dct = dict(zip(list(string.ascii_uppercase) + list(np.arange(2, 9)), np.arange(1, 34)))
# If they are strings of numbers, not integers use:
#dct = dict(zip(list(string.ascii_uppercase) + ['2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8'], np.arange(1, 34)))

df.col_name = df.col_name.map(dct)
```

---

An example:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [2, 4, 6, 3, 5, 'A', 'B', 'D', 'F', 'Z', 'X']})
df.col.map(dct)
```

Outputs:

```
0     27
1     29
2     31
3     28
4     30
5      1
6      2
7      4
8      6
9     26
10    24
Name: col, dtype: int64
```

Comment: When I apply this to my data frame in it works great for the entries which are letters, but then returns NaN for the numbers. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @AaronEngland are your numbers in your `DataFrame` column actually being stored as strings, i.e. `'2'` instead of `2`. If so, just modify the keys in the dictionary when you create it. See my update for how to create the new dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

i think that could help you
[Replacing letters with numbers with its position in alphabet](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/183658/replacing-letters-with-numbers-with-its-position-in-alphabet)

then you just need to `apply` on you df column

```
dt.Var1.apply(alphabet_position)
```

you can also try this

```
for i in range(len(var1)):
    if type(var1[i]) == int:
        var1[i] = var1[i] + 25
    else:
        var1[i] = ord(var1[i].lower()) - 96
```